# How to modify one file in one sub-folder using another file in another subfolder in the same parent folder?

Tags: c#, file, directory

Say I have user provided path "D:\TestPath" and inside **TestPath** are folders 1024, 32112, 780 etc where each of those folders
have two immediate subfolders one of which is named **abc** and the other subfolder has a subfolder which is named **xyz**.

Each of the main folder inside **TestPath** i.e. folders 1024, 32112, 780 etc have a **abc** and **xyz** folders and each of them have a text file.

How do I copy some text from the text file in folder **abc** and paste or do whatever I want to the text file inside **xyz** folders for each folders 1024, 32112, 780 using c#?

Folder structure of 1024, 32112, 780 are as follows:

```
1024\abc\1.txt
    \221\xyz\a.txt

32112\abc\2.txt
    \521\xyz\p.txt
....
```

Comment: There isn't a single method call in the .NET framework that does what you want to do, for reasons which I hope are obvious. Break the problem down into smaller problems and solve each one. If you break it down into small enough pieces, each piece will be trivial. This isn't an optimizing compiler here, it's just some file IO in a loop. Write out the steps to do what you want. When you get to a high level abstraction like "paste or do whatever", break that down into steps too. Don't just stare at a complicated problem. Break it down into pieces.

Comment: Once you have some code written, you can come here asking for help if you run into specific programming problems. As it is, you're just asking us to write your code for you, and so the question doesn't belong here. [This article may help clarify what we consider a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

We're not going to write your code for you. However, I'll provide you with the following information which should enable you to do what you want.

Create a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` containing all of your pairs of files where the key is the first file and the value is the second.

This could be generated by looping over the folders using `Directory.GetFiles()`.

From here, you can iterate over the pairs using `File.ReadAllLines()` to get a `string[]` of the the contents of each (store in another `KVP`).

You could then use a `Regex` to find the text in the second array and replace the relevant text in the first.

From here, you can use `File.WriteAllLines()` to overwrite the original file with the contents of your modified `string[]`.

Whilst I appreciate this doesn't fully answer your question, which was very vague, it should provide you with the tools you need to do so.

If it doesn't help at all, please let me know and if you provide more detail of your problem I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: How do I create `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` containing all of my pairs of files. I can think of getting the pairs in two different arrays like `var files1 = Directory.GetDirectories(@D:\TestPath, "abc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .SelectMany(d => Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.txt")).ToArray();` and `var files2 = Directory.GetDirectories(@D:\TestPath, "xyz", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .SelectMany(d => Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.txt")).ToArray();` but then how do I know which files data to copy and on which file to paste?

Comment: Also if the file names were identical it would not have been a problem but that is not the case.

Comment: @TamalBanerjee How are you determining which files get paired with which?

Comment: I can't determine which files are paired, thats the problem..if both the files inside **abc** and **xyz** had the same name then `File.Exists()` might have been used but that is not the case here...

Comment: I don't mean programmatically, I mean what are the criteria you're actually programming to? Like which file gets copied into which? Is there a directory structure to follow?